# Calling setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled for fragments in ActionBarCompat

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat

I am using ActionBarCompat. When I load a child fragment, I want the home button to work as the up button. So I called this from the child fragment:

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But still the home button is not being shown as the up button. I have also added logic for the id `android.R.id.home` in `onOptionsItemSelected`, but it still does not work. Any ideas how I can get it done?

Answer (score 10):

I've struggled with this for a couple of long days, and here's what I've found to work. I'm hoping there's a better solution, but this does get the job done:

In my main activity (the one launching the fragment), create the following public function, which will be called by the "child" fragment:

```
// The method is in MainActivity.java
public void resetActionBar(boolean childAction, int drawerMode)
{
    if (childAction) {
        // [Undocumented?] trick to get up button icon to show
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    } else {
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    }

    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(drawerMode);
}
```

Then, from your fragment that you want the Up button to appear, just call that method as follows (adapting class names as needed):

```
// This method in in SomeFragment.java
((MainActivity)getActivity()).resetActionBar(true,
      DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

To summarize, here's how to enable up button from fragment:

- Disable the drawer indicator on the drawerToggle object -- call setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)
- Set displayHomeAsUp -- call setDisplayHomeAsUpEnable(true) on actionBar object
- Optionally, lock the drawer, so it won't appear on edge swipe

Hope this helps, and I'm hoping this becomes easier in the future...

Comment: I had same problem. I tried you solution. It now shows the Up button,but the click event on UP button does nothing. I does not moves back. I have override `onOptionsItemSelected` in fragment,but it nothing. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
class ABC : Fragment()  {
    override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? { {

        (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a description to your answer explaining where it should go and prob what the OP was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party:)

I'm sharing this so that it might help someone. I have head around lots of solutions and none of them works perfectly. I've used variation of solutions available in my project which is here as below. Please use this code inside class where you are initialising toolbar and drawer layout.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                drawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);// show back button
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                //show hamburger
                drawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                drawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.syncState();
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        drawerFragment.mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I referenced the answer and take a change like this:

```
//add third parameter for Fragment
    public void resetActionBar(boolean childAction, int drawerMode , final Fragment fragment) {
        if (childAction) {
            // [Undocumented?] trick to get up button icon to show
            actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            });
        } else {
            actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        }
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(drawerMode);
    }
```

and i call this function in other fragment like this:

```
//new Homepage it's my one of fragments , you can pick up your destination
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).resetActionBar(true,DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED,new HomePage());
```

I'm still confused about life circle issue , may this helpful for you.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, also dont forget to mention  parent activity and meta data for the activity in the manifest

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
        // NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        // finish();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You can't set parent activities in the manifest for a fragment. 2. The question is not about how to handle the itemSelected event, but rather how to change the up button in the action bar.